# SOQL query with 'LIKE not giving expected results

Tags: apex, soql, query, sosl, custom-metadata

In my org, I've set up some custom metadata on which I have all text fields which I am querying. 
On my query without anything in the `where` condition

```
SELECT Label,Fields__c,Labels__c,Scheme__c from ClickWrap_Sections__mdt
```

I get, 
[image]

When I run the query as

```
SELECT Label, Fields__c, Labels__c, Scheme__c from ClickWrap_Sections__mdt where Scheme__c=null OR Scheme__c like '%PL%'
```

It returns me only the list of records that have `Scheme__c` set to null 
[image]

Again, if I remove the null check and run the query as just

```
SELECT Label, Fields__c, Labels__c, Scheme__c from ClickWrap_Sections__mdt where Scheme__c like '%PL%'
```

It returns me the two records that match the criteria 
[image]

I would like to understand how can I get the records that have `Scheme__c`as null or match a particular criteria in the same query and why the first query doesn't work.

Comment: Seems like it might be related to this known issue - https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001BreQAE&title=custom-metadata-type-not-being-sorted-as-expected

Comment: The known issue [Soql on metadata type records does not work properly when using LIKE in OR relationship](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001FT4JQAW) is describing similar issue

Comment: I think SOQL on metadata doesn't work with OR in it as https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_limitations.htm specifies AND but no OR under SOQLs.